# Configure Chef Server's FQDN in Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu, chef-infra

I have been hitting a wall configuring a Chef server running Ubuntu which I created in Azure (ARM Deployment).  Regardless of what I have tried, I cannot figure out how to change the server's management FQDN URL's.

Here are some facts about the installation

- I created a VM in Azure via that Chef Server 12, BYOL template
- I have a public IP address with DNS label setup
- I am able to SSH into the machine
  via the DNS assigned to the public IP
- I have updated the hostname of
  the machine to use the FQDN via `sudo hostname  fakechefserver.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com` and confirmed it is correct by calling `hostname -f`
- I ensured https, http, ssh and https8443 ports are open in network security group (NSG)
- I have modified
  /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb as follows (from 
  https://learn.chef.io/install-and-manage-your-own-chef-server/linux/install-chef-server/install-chef-server-using-your-hardware/#step3 )

  ```
  server_name = "fakechefserver.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com"
  api_fqdn server_name
  bookshelf['vip'] = server_name
  nginx['url'] = "https://#{server_name}"
  nginx['server_name'] = server_name
  nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/#{server_name}.crt"
  nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/#{server_name}.key"
  ```

The problem is that after I reconfigured the server using `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` and then rebooted the box, the url to https://fakechefserver.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com does not connect.

Furthermore, when I SSH into the machine, it tells me the management URL is https://devops-chef-server.************.bx.internal.cloudapp.net (where devops-chef-server is the azure name for the Public IP address).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know a lot about chef (its one of those things on my list!) But it could be that chef is doing a reverse lookup on its IP address (which I can only presume it is getting from a forward lookup) Have you tried setting a reverse lookup address?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Michael- I have not tried doing that yet.